# Wordpress Home page Image

Tags: wordpress

i have a question, on home page on  http://poshpanel.com/  , the featured image after chosen gets cropped to 600x250 and gets placed on the home screen as shown in the below posts.

I want to make that bigger, what can be done to make it bigger and more noticeable.

photo crop URL http://poshpanel.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Pamela-Skaist-Levy-and-Gela-Nash-Taylor-1-600x250.jpg

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: may be the size is defined in admin settings -> media

Comment: What are you using to call the photo on the homepage? Wordpress automatically generates different sizes of the photo, depending on what you're using to retrieve that image, you can specify what size you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a custom thumbnail size defined in functions.php. Look for [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) in the functions.php file for your theme.

However, from glancing at the theme changing the size of that image may also require changes to the size of the main content area.